# ServiceClient default RetryStrategy

Tags: c#, swagger

I noticed that the default behavior of my Swagger generated proxy is to retry when a 500 is thrown. How can a retry strategy be default? Should be Opt in if you ask me not opt out like now. Crazy. Anyway, this works but it feels like a lot of code to disable this strange behavior, any better way?

```
var service = new MyService(uri, credentials);
service.SetRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy(new HttpStatusCodeErrorDetectionStrategy(), 0));
```

When on earth do you want the default to be to retry when a 500 happens, its absurd.